# How to only listen once on $document from inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that needs to listen for `click` events on `$document`.
Let's call it **clickDirective**.

The click listener is added inside its `link` function.
The problem is that if there are multiple clickDirectives in the document, each one adds a new `click` listener on `$document` resulting in a document click handler function firing once for each clickDirective on the page. I only want it to fire once.

However, the callback function should be scoped inside the `link` function so that it has access to `scope`, `element` and `attrs` for example.

I tried adding it to the `compile` function and while the click handler only fires once, its callback handler doesn't have access to the goodies inside the `link` function.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Have an example/plunker to play with?

Comment: Why do you bind your event to $document and not to directive element?

Comment: You say you only want to bind it once but then you also say that you want the click handler to have access to scope, element and attrs. But if there are multiple directives on the page there will be different scope, element and attrs for each one, so which should it have access to? The solution to your problem sounds like it may be a service, but it's hard to know with the current description.

Comment: Clicking inside the directive shows a bubble. To hide it you have to click outside the directive, so I listen on the document and check if the event.target is contained within the directive's `element`.'

Comment: The current workaround is I only add the document click handler inside each directive if a click occurs and remove the document click handler from inside the document click handler itself.

Comment: That actually sounds like a good solution. You only want to listen for the click while the bubble is shown and it shouldn't have to worry about other instances of the directive on the page. The handler is specific to the directive so you don't want just one existing for all directives, it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I need this (document click handler) is that if other bubbles are visible, opening another must close all others.

Comment: You definitely need a service then, see the second part of my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you say that you want to listen on $document for a click and use it to close a popover bubble. So I think it probably is correct to listen to the event from within the directive.

You can use `one` instead of `on` to bind the event only for one event (it'll unbind itself after the first click). So something like this:

```
module.directive('bubble', function ($document) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function () {
        scope.$apply(function(){
          // Show the bubble here
          $document.one('click', function () {
            scope.$apply(function(){
              // Hide the bubble here
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

If you really did want to listen only once on the $document you would use a service, but then you wouldn't have access to scope, element and attrs (because for which element would you expect them to be?). You could create a service that listens once then tracks the bubbles to be closed which would look something like this:

```
module.factory('bubbleCloser', function ($document, $rootScope) { 
  var toClose = [];
  $document.on('click', function () {
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
      toClose.forEach(function (element) {
        element.hide();
      });
      toClose = [];
    });
  });
  return {
    addBubbleElement: function (element) {
      toClose.push(element);
    }
  };
});
```

Which meets your original requirements of only listening to click once but is more complicated and doesn't give any benefits really (but maybe is useful if there's more to this that you haven't shown).

Comment: Hm, I thought DOM logic was supposed to only go in directives. Is it an accepted practice to use services for DOM logic?

Comment: Yes, I think it's ok if that logic does not correspond to a single directive on the page. I would really avoid mixing DOM logic and non-DOM logic in the same service.

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds very similar to Angular UI's popover directive: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

Comment: Similar, but without the overhead of Bootstrap. Thanks, Thomas.

Comment: I think you can actually supply your own templates for Angular UI if you want, so it's not actually dependant on Bootstrap. I think you can also extract just the bits you need (ie just popover). Don't know if that helps, but just thought I'd mention it :)

Comment: .one will still add multiple event listeners to $document, but will only execute its given function once. so if you have 3 instances of the directive,  the function will execute 3 times and then the listener will be removed. in my interpretation the original question was about attaching only 1 listener for multiple instance